# Map file in the Integration for the LogicApp in Azure

Tags: json, xml, azure, integration, azure-logic-apps

Have the following XML as a result of the HTTP GET function from the B2B supplier.

```
<Invoices xmlns="http://gateway.com/schemas/Invoices" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://gateway..com/schemas/Invoices Invoices.xsd">
   <DocumentInfo>
      <DocType>INVOICES</DocType>
      <DocVersion>2.0</DocVersion>
   </DocumentInfo>
   <Header>
      <StartDate>2018-12-01T00:00:00+01:00</StartDate>
      <EndDate>2019-01-03T00:00:00+01:00</EndDate>
   </Header>
   <Documents>
      <Invoice InvoiceId="RP82807" InvoiceDate="2019-01-02T00:00:00+01:00" DocumentType="IN" RefDocId="FT34532" RefDocType="ORDER" SystemId="10" HasPDFImage="0" />
      <Invoice InvoiceId="T609881" InvoiceDate="2018-12-31T00:00:00+01:00" DocumentType="IN" RefDocId="FT39339" RefDocType="ORDER" SystemId="0" HasPDFImage="0" />
   </Documents>
</Invoices>
```

Based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#more-liquid-action-examples) I've created the liquid map file to get the list of InvoiceIds:

```
{
"Invoice": "{{content.Documents.Invoice}}"
}
```

When using it in the LogicApp in the XML->Json converter, got the following result:

```
{
    "Invoice": ""
}
```

I have also tried this as a liquid file:

```
{
"Invoice": "{{content.Invoices.Documents}}"
}
```

and this:

```
{
"Invoice": "{{content.Invoices.Documents.Invoice}}"
}
```

with the same result. 
Can you give me a tip what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to transfer part of your xml file to json with this map:

```
{
"DocType":"{{content.DocumentInfo.DocType}}",
"Invoice":"{{content.Documents.Invoice}}"
}
```

And get the output:

```
{
"DocType": "INVOICES",
"Invoice": ""
}
```

So this means I can get the **DocType** but can't get **Invoice** properties, so I think maybe the Liquid map doesn't support the XML format. Maybe you could change it to like this:

```
<Invoice>
<InvoiceId>T609881</InvoiceId>
  <InvoiceDate>2018-12-31T00:00:00+01:00</InvoiceDate>
  <DocumentType>IN</DocumentType>
  <RefDocId>FT39339</RefDocId>
</Invoice>
```

This will work, or you could go to Liquid [reference](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid) to check is there any methods to match the properties.

[image]

**Note:what you want for now,binding to Xml Attributes is not currently supported.You could refer to this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/282030b9-c1ea-4af4-ab99-35ea04d6e705/jsonarrayfor-not-picking-up-xml-attribute?forum=azureapimgmt).**

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

**UPDATE:You still could do it with logic app.** For example I used a FTP connector to get xml file content then create a json with  "json(xml(body('Get_file_content')))" expression.
[image]

**And this is the result.**
[image]

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately, I do not have an influence on the XML format of the source file. I guess I need to create an XSLT map file instead. Do you have any tips on how to do this? I found [this](http://www.bizcoder.com/convert-xml-to-json-using-xslt)  sample code but unfortunately, it doesn't work in Azure.

Comment: @Michal Z. I have updated my answer, you could check it. If this could help you, you could mark it.

Comment: @Michal Z. If my answer works, you could mark my answer. Thanks!

Comment: this was exactly this what I was looking for. Instead, I initiated variable which converts the XML into JSON. But your example is working as well. Thx a lot.